# Screen too small for raspberry pi

Tags: raspbian, screen

I have a Pi 3 Model B+ and ordered a Kuman 3.5 tft LCD Display (The resolution is 320x480). 
I got the display to work but when I open the terminal it is too big for the screen. I changed the resolution on raspi-config to 640x480 but it is still too big
I also attempted changing the /boot/config.txt to:

```
framebuffer_width=480
framebuffer_height=320
```

I have `disable_overscan=1` commented since there are no black spaces on the screen. Also all the overscan options are commented out
Any help configuring the display?

Comment: What is your settings on `/etc/modules`?

Comment: it only has 'i2c-dev'

Comment: Based on [this tutorial](http://www.circuitbasics.com/setup-lcd-touchscreen-raspberry-pi/), it seems that you need to add certain setting in `etc/modules`, but that's is not based on Kumantech's TFT. However, I've seen on the internet someone claims that the tutorial works for Kumantech's TFT. Hope this point you to some right direction.

Comment: It should be like this. framebuffer_width=320
framebuffer_height=480